# Making a kind of a browser based Python IDLE that also allows the user of files

Tags: python, pyscript, brython

The title more or less tells it all. Ideally, I would like the html as self-sufficient as possible and definitely run the code in the browser. In addition, I would like be able to:

- use files, including uploading files and viewing text files, in addition of course to being able to run files.
- writing at least short text files.
- type and run code directly in the interpreter/terminal.
- use most modules in the Python standard library, but especially random, os, datetime, time and pickle.

I was experimenting with [brython-runner](https://github.com/pythonpad/brython-runner) obviously based on [Brython](https://brython.info/). However, I would be perfectly happy using some other tool, e.g. [PyScript](https://pyscript.com/) or combination of them.

What I succeeded was in making a basic interpreter that runs the code from the "editor" pane in another pane, but this involved practically just copying the code from [brython-runner](https://github.com/pythonpad/brython-runner) or more precisely [index.html from there](https://github.com/pythonpad/brython-runner/blob/master/index.html) and running a locally a handler from https://github.com/pythonpad/brython-runner-stdin-hanger for input to work (pythonpad handler does not work at the time of writing).

What I would like is at least to also use files (see above), if tying in the "interpreter" would be allowed, this would be even better. I noticed that [brython-runner](https://github.com/pythonpad/brython-runner)  also mentions `runCodeWithFiles`, but I was not able to get this to work. Bellow is my miserable attempt.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.58.2/codemirror.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.58.2/codemirror.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.58.2/theme/ayu-mirage.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.58.2/mode/python/python.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.58.2/addon/comment/comment.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.58.2/keymap/sublime.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    <script src="./brython-runner.bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dev-box">
        <div class="toolbar-row">
            <button class="toolbar-button" onclick="run()">
                Run
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="workspace-row">
            <div class="editor-column">
                <div class="editor" id="editor"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="run-column">
                <div class="output-box" id="output">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        // Initialize the code editor.
        const CODEMIRROR_OPTIONS = {
            lineNumbers: true,
            lineSeparator: '\n',
            mode: undefined,
            theme: 'ayu-mirage',
            fontSize: 14,
            indentUnit: 4,
            tabSize: 4,
            indentWithTabs: false,
            lineWrapping: true,
            readOnly: false,
            smartIndent: true,
            matchBrackets: true,
            autoCloseBrackets: true,
            showTrailingSpace: true,
            keyMap: 'sublime',
            extraKeys: null,
            showInvisibles: true,
            viewportMargin: Infinity,
        }
        const codeStoreKey = 'brython-runner-dev-code'
        const loadedCode = localStorage.getItem(codeStoreKey)
        const code = loadedCode || 'print("hello world")'
        const editor = CodeMirror(document.getElementById('editor'), {
            ...CODEMIRROR_OPTIONS,
            mode: 'python',
            value: code,
        })
        editor.on('change', (editor, change) => {
            localStorage.setItem(codeStoreKey, editor.getDoc().getValue())
        })
        const files = {
            'data/': {
                'type': 'dir',
                'body': '',
            },
            'data/rac.txt': {
                'type': 'text',
                'body': '''izdelek  cena    kolicina
Jajca   0.20    6
Kruh    1.80    1
Salama  5.75    0.40
''',            
            },
            'main.py': {
                'type': 'text',
                'body': '',
            }
        };
        const runner = new BrythonRunner({
            onFileUpdate(filename, data) {
                files[filename].type = data.type;
                files[filename].body = data.body;
            },
            hangerUrl: 'http://localhost:9095/hanger',
            stdout: {
                write(content) {
                    var el = document.createElement('code')
                    var text = document.createTextNode(content)
                    el.appendChild(text)
                    document.getElementById('output').appendChild(el)  
                },
                flush() { }
            },
            stderr: {
                write(content) {
                    var el = document.createElement('code')
                    var text = document.createTextNode(content)
                    el.appendChild(text)
                    el.setAttribute('class', 'error')
                    document.getElementById('output').appendChild(el)
                },
                flush() { }
            },
            stdin: {
                async readline() {
                    var data = prompt()
                    
                    var el = document.createElement('code')
                    var text = document.createTextNode(data + '\n')
                    el.appendChild(text)
                    document.getElementById('output').appendChild(el)  

                    return data
                },
            }
        })
        function clearOutput() {
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = ''
        }
        function getCode() {
            return editor.getDoc().getValue()
        }
        function run() {
            clearOutput()
            runner.runCodeWithFiles(files['main.py'].body, files);
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd have to ask why not use [JupyterLite](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) where this is already done and working? As for "type and run code directly in the interpreter/terminal": a good example of how that is possible too is seen [here](https://groups.google.com/g/sympy/c/mX2Ckn7ru3A/m/utrLb-NnAAAJ) describing how the SymPy shell was customized from the JupyterLite REPL to make what is [here](https://live.sympy.org/) that you can get to by going to the main SymPy site and clicking on 'Try SymPy online now' in the Quick Links list on the right side. As for using files, for now...

Comment: <continued> you treat the running JupyterLite as if the session inside the browser is a remote computer and use can drag-and-drop in the local files from the local computer into the file navigation panel in the main JupyterLab-like interface of JupyterLite. My understanding is that basic browser security approaches for now make that the only real way to go between local system files and the virtual file system in browser-based JupyterLite session. Download from the virtual file system to local is treated similarly. There's ongoing discussion of clever ways to make this file stuff easier.